# How can I make a "Token Counter" in Solana smart contract?

Tags: rust, smartcontracts, solana

I want to create a "token counter" which value increases after each token sale. I should make a struct, However I don't know how to store it to be able to keep for next contract calling and use that.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

This question can be a matter of opinion and design, but you can create a new on-chain program that handles your token sales.  In your program, you'll have accounts to store any data that you need, including a "token counter".

Here are a few resources to help you out:

- example hello world program: https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld
- escrow tutorial: https://paulx.dev/blog/2021/01/14/programming-on-solana-an-introduction/